# What is the URL to check if updates exists based on a given version of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am automating the process of updating Visual Studio Code. What is the URL / API to check if an update exists for a given version number?

I see StateType.CheckingForUpdates in [update.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/704bf0f2cc0346be0482e241d9aecdfd3e6a2741/src/vs/workbench/contrib/update/browser/update.ts)

Comment: you can check if there is an `/updates/v1_XX` with a higher number than your version. the highest number is the latest version. get `https://code.visualstudio.com/updates` and look for the HTTP redirect (status 302)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Microsoft's `.deb` package repository and get the latest version using a regex on the packet name, together with numeric sort.

There are two ways to get the package list: Either parsing the [directory listing](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/pool/main/c/code/) of the folder containing the `.deb` files, or parsing [the `Packages.gz` file](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/)... Since the first approach is easier and generates less internet traffic (although arguably less robust), I'll go with that one.

```
curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/pool/main/c/code/ \
   | sed -nE 's/.*code_([0-9.]*).*amd64\.deb.*/\1/p' \
   | sort --version-sort \
   | tail -n1
```

To break it apart:

- `curl` downloads the list of deb files, an nginx directory listing, which contains lines like this one:

  ```
  <a href="code_1.83.0-1696350811_amd64.deb">code_1.83.0-1696350811_amd64.deb</a>                                                                    04-Oct-2023 18:05
  ```
- `sed` searches for lines containing something like `*code_${numbers_and_dots}*amd64.deb*` and prints only the `${numbers_and_dots}` part. *(You can write `armhf` or `arm64` instead of `amd64` for the other architectures).*
- `sort --version-sort` sorts those version numbers numerically, so that `1.83` comes after `1.9` although 9 is lexically greater than 8.  *Requires GNU sort.*
- `tail -n1` prints just the last (newest) version number.

Answer (score -1):

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43

All updates available here !!

Comment: Thanks for the URL but I am trying to automate the process and cannot hard code the version number in the URL.